# How Ignite performs cache.get() operation when hashCode is overridden?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ignite

See the image attached below.

[Image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hi4h.png)

I have put keys into the cache using the equals 
method as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    HierarchyMasterKey hierarchyMasterKey = (HierarchyMasterKey) obj;   

    return  equalTo(this.hmCustNo, hierarchyMasterKey.hmCustNo) &&
            equalTo(this.hmFromDate, hierarchyMasterKey.hmFromDate) &&
            equalTo(this.hmParentCustNo, hierarchyMasterKey.hmParentCustNo) &&
            equalTo(this.hmActNo, hierarchyMasterKey.hmActNo);

 }
```

(equalTo method is basically null safe equals check.)

and hashCode is computed as below:

```
    @Override 
    public int hashCode() { 
            return Objects.hash(hmCustNo,hmActNo); 
    }
```

When I try to get from it, 
the equals method won't get executed. Why is this so? How does ignite get 
the key without executing equals?

[I have a cache that has a HierarchyMasterKey and a list of HierarchyMaster 
as values and using Externalizable to override hashcode and equals]

Answer (score 1):

Ignite will compare keys on field-by-field (this includes field ordering) by default, in binary serialized form.

`hashCode` will only be used when your class implements `Externalizable`. This has performance implications.

You can also implement `Binarylizable` and implement corresponding methods to affect how objects are stored and compared.

Comment: In fact, I am using Externalizable. Hash code is computed and equals method is executed for put operations. But while get operation is performed, hash code is computed, but it does not execute equals method, that is the problem. Can you please check the image attached.

Comment: @JikkuJoyce Yes you are right, when working with off-heap Ignite will still compare binary representations of types and not use `equals`. Why `hashCode` is used is confusing to me either.

Comment: Its for getting the level of the tree for search, @alamar

Comment: @JikkuJoyce still it's not obvious why not just compute hashsum of binary representation

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem here. Its actually an interesting observation.

My cache had on heap disabled. Ignite will do a BPlusTree search for off heap items, where it does not need equals method to be executed to find the result.

If its enabled, it will work just like a hashmap get operation.